# Why Material Top Tabs could not be found even though I installed it? (React Native)

Tags: react-native, error-handling, react-navigation-top-tabs

I installed the Material Top Tab library and I imported it on the project but it occurs me an error it says:

"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs" could not be found within the project or in these directories:
..\node_modules@react-native

I don't know what the error is!

Answer (score 0):

Before installing

```
npm install @react-navigation/material-top-tabs react-native-tab-view react-native-pager-view
```

I installed

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

And after that I reinstalled **npm install @react-navigation/material-top-tabs react-native-tab-view react-native-pager-view** and it worked.

Comment: I am having the same issue and tried the suggested solution and it did not resolve the problem.